# Python: Shuffling and dealing cards to 4 Players using random

Tags: python-3.x, random, shuffle

How can I shuffle a cards deck for 4 players and make sure they all get different cards?
I keep getting same cards for different players.

As you see in the code below>>>>> I have tried to solve this problem by using:   "carddeck.remove(carddeck[i])".

Which apparently was not so useful-for the simple reason that it was !!only!! blocking the next player to get same cards as the previous one.
But it didn't block the option of getting same cards for example to player 4 and player 1 .

I think there is something I am terribly missing here .

**Shuffle a deck**

```
import itertools
import random
carddeck = list(itertools.product(range(1,14),["Spade", "Club", "Diamond","Heart"]))
#print(carddeck)

#random.shuffle(carddeck)
#print (carddeck)

def player1(n):
    for i in range(n):
        carddeck = list(itertools.product(range(1,14),["Spade", "Club", "Diamond", "Heart"]))
        random.shuffle(carddeck)
        print("Player1:",carddeck[i][0],carddeck[i][1])
        carddeck.remove(carddeck[i])
        #print (carddeck)
def player2(n):
    for j in range(n):
         random.shuffle(carddeck)
         print("Player2:",carddeck[j][0],carddeck[j][1])
         carddeck.remove(carddeck[j])


def player3(n):
    for f in range(n):
         random.shuffle(carddeck)
         print("Player3:",carddeck[f][0],carddeck[f][1])
         carddeck.remove(carddeck[f])


def player4(n):
    for g in range(n):
         random.shuffle(carddeck)
         print("Player4:", carddeck[g][0],carddeck[g][1])
player1(2)
player2(2)
player3(2)
player4(2)
```

**Output**

```
Player1: 3 Club
Player1: 5 Spade
Player2: 7 Diamond
Player2: 10 Diamond
Player3: 3 Club
Player3: 2 Spade
Player4: 13 Diamond
Player4: 1 Spade
```

Comment: Why are you building the deck three times (up front, and twice again inside player1()), and then shuffling it for every card? Just, build it, shuffle it, then deal as many cards as needed, removing them as they are dealt.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something like this. hope this helps you!

```
# Python program to shuffle a deck of card using the module random and draw 5 cards

# import modules
import itertools, random

# make a deck of cards
deck = list(itertools.product([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K'],
                              ['Spade', 'Heart', 'Diamond', 'Club']))

# shuffle the cards
random.shuffle(deck)

# draw cards, a total of 48 cards divided among 6 players 
print("Player 1 got:")

for i in range(8):
    print(deck[i][0], "of", deck[i][1])
    deck.remove(deck[i])
print("Player 2 got:") 
for j in range(8):
    print(deck[j][0], "of", deck[j][1])
    deck.remove(deck[j])
print("Player 3 got:")
for k in range(8):
    print(deck[k][0], "of", deck[k][1])
    deck.remove(deck[k])
print("Player 4 got:") 
for l in range(8):
    print(deck[l][0], "of", deck[l][1])
    deck.remove(deck[l])
print("Player 5 got:")
for m in range(8):
    print(deck[m][0], "of", deck[m][1])
    deck.remove(deck[m])
print("Player 6 got:") 
for n in range(8):
    print(deck[n][0], "of", deck[n][1])
```